# Optimizing time series data retrieval

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

So I've been messing around for a couple days trying to figure out how to get my queries to run faster in postgres because they're running prohibitively slow but I haven't made much progress. I'm hoping I can get some feedback on how to make this better.

I have a table that stores many records. The data is pretty typical except for one feature that is of type `jsonb` and is used to hold dictionaries that can get quite large (thousands of entries in the dictionary).

The query that I need to run faster is one like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM msft_042319 WHERE time BETWEEN 34200000000000.0 AND 34560000000000.0 ORDER BY time;
```

Which currently takes ~20 seconds to execute through `psycopg2` in Python. (strictly to get results, no data processing) and returns 25,073 records.

I've tried using `timescaledb` to make this faster but I haven't noticed much of an improvement. (Probably because timescale expects observations on the order of millions for processing).

Suggestions appreciated. My code runs but it's not much better than broken since the data retrieval step is prohibitively slow.

---

##### Execution Plan

QUERY

```
explain (analyze, buffers, format text) SELECT * FROM msft_042319 WHERE time BETWEEN 34200000000000.0 AND 34560000000000.0 ORDER BY time;
```

RESPONSE

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Gather Merge  (cost=5469.66..5568.80 rows=828 width=70) (actual time=18.305..27.329 rows=25073 loops=1)
   Workers Planned: 4
   Workers Launched: 4
   Buffers: shared hit=2644 dirtied=1078
   ->  Sort  (cost=4469.60..4470.12 rows=207 width=70) (actual time=12.904..13.155 rows=5015 loops=5)
         Sort Key: _hyper_1_12_chunk."time"
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1745kB
         Buffers: shared hit=2644 dirtied=1078
         Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1135kB
         Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1066kB
         Worker 2:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1033kB
         Worker 3:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1034kB
         ->  Parallel Append  (cost=0.00..4461.64 rows=207 width=70) (actual time=1.071..11.515 rows=5015 loops=5)
               Buffers: shared hit=2492 dirtied=1078
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on _hyper_1_12_chunk  (cost=0.00..3794.44 rows=429 width=63) (actual time=0.021..10.211 rows=5015 loops=5)
                     Filter: ((("time")::numeric >= 34200000000000.0) AND (("time")::numeric <= 34560000000000.0))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 24164
                     Buffers: shared hit=2078 dirtied=1078
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on _hyper_1_13_chunk  (cost=0.00..423.15 rows=59 width=46) (actual time=4.714..4.714 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Filter: ((("time")::numeric >= 34200000000000.0) AND (("time")::numeric <= 34560000000000.0))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 19926
                     Buffers: shared hit=189
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on _hyper_1_11_chunk  (cost=0.00..128.33 rows=1 width=1440) (actual time=0.244..0.244 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Filter: ((("time")::numeric >= 34200000000000.0) AND (("time")::numeric <= 34560000000000.0))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 453
                     Buffers: shared hit=123
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on _hyper_1_8_chunk  (cost=0.00..28.81 rows=1 width=711) (actual time=0.054..0.054 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Filter: ((("time")::numeric >= 34200000000000.0) AND (("time")::numeric <= 34560000000000.0))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 239
                     Buffers: shared hit=26
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on _hyper_1_9_chunk  (cost=0.00..22.61 rows=1 width=916) (actual time=0.055..0.055 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Filter: ((("time")::numeric >= 34200000000000.0) AND (("time")::numeric <= 34560000000000.0))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 137
                     Buffers: shared hit=21
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on _hyper_1_7_chunk  (cost=0.00..20.28 rows=1 width=608) (actual time=0.049..0.049 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Filter: ((("time")::numeric >= 34200000000000.0) AND (("time")::numeric <= 34560000000000.0))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 194
                     Buffers: shared hit=18
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on _hyper_1_10_chunk  (cost=0.00..17.27 rows=1 width=934) (actual time=0.040..0.040 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Filter: ((("time")::numeric >= 34200000000000.0) AND (("time")::numeric <= 34560000000000.0))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 108
                     Buffers: shared hit=16
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on _hyper_1_6_chunk  (cost=0.00..5.86 rows=1 width=397) (actual time=0.022..0.022 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Filter: ((("time")::numeric >= 34200000000000.0) AND (("time")::numeric <= 34560000000000.0))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 73
                     Buffers: shared hit=5
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on _hyper_1_1_chunk  (cost=0.00..5.44 rows=1 width=198) (actual time=0.022..0.022 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Filter: ((("time")::numeric >= 34200000000000.0) AND (("time")::numeric <= 34560000000000.0))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 122
                     Buffers: shared hit=4
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on _hyper_1_4_chunk  (cost=0.00..3.68 rows=1 width=337) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Filter: ((("time")::numeric >= 34200000000000.0) AND (("time")::numeric <= 34560000000000.0))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 58
                     Buffers: shared hit=3
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on _hyper_1_2_chunk  (cost=0.00..3.62 rows=1 width=280) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Filter: ((("time")::numeric >= 34200000000000.0) AND (("time")::numeric <= 34560000000000.0))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 53
                     Buffers: shared hit=3
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on _hyper_1_3_chunk  (cost=0.00..3.59 rows=1 width=316) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Filter: ((("time")::numeric >= 34200000000000.0) AND (("time")::numeric <= 34560000000000.0))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 50
                     Buffers: shared hit=3
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on _hyper_1_5_chunk  (cost=0.00..3.52 rows=1 width=369) (actual time=0.014..0.015 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Filter: ((("time")::numeric >= 34200000000000.0) AND (("time")::numeric <= 34560000000000.0))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 44
                     Buffers: shared hit=3
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=1053 dirtied=4
 Planning Time: 2.076 ms
 Execution Time: 28.432 ms
(70 rows)
```

Comment: made the requested edit

Comment: The execution time **one the server** is only 28 **milli**seconds - so that's far from the 20 _seconds_ you are seeing. The overhead is cause by network transfer and processing time (probably in the python database driver/library)

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need more information. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question. It's likely that replacing `SELECT *` with something more specific will help. Also, databases with hundreds of tables often perform more poorly than those with dozens, because of caching.